# TOP function in SQL Server 2005 not giving correct answer

Tags: sql-server-2005

How can I use `TOP` function in SQL Server 2005 on a single column in a table along with count function?

I am getting only one count for this query, where I have 35 entries that should come.
this is my query

```
select top(1) room_no, count(room_no) from rooms
```

Comment: tried with a `group by`?

Comment: post sample data to ilustrate question.

Comment: By using `TOP(1)` you are requesting: *give me the **one** top row* and that's exactly what you're getting. Also: you have no `ORDER BY` so the ordering is **not defined** - it could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what you want is the following:

```
select room_no,count(room_no)
from rooms
group by room_no
```

BTW, I wonder why it would execute without the `group by`. Should throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

COUNT function is evaluated after TOP. That is why you are only getting one for the count. What you want is something like this

```
SELECT TOP(1) dbo.Table.Column1, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Table)
FROM dbo.Table
```

Also as mentioned you really should be ordering by something.

Edit: This also works:

```
SELECT TOP(1) dbo.Table.Column1, COUNT(*) OVER() AS Total
FROM dbo.Table
```

Seems to be more efficient as well (only tested on small dataset though).

Comment: select top(1)rd.room_no, count(distinct rd.room_no) available_d
from room_details rd left join rooms r on rd.room_no=r.room_no 
where rd.room_status='A' and rd.room_no not in
( select  rd.room_no from room_details rd left join rooms r on rd.room_no=r.room_no 
where rd.room_status='A'
and ((2012-08-03)>=r.check_in_date 
and (2012-08-03)<=r.check_out_date) 
or ((2012-08-03)>=r.check_in_date 
and (2012-08-03)<=r.check_out_date) and type='delux') and type='delux' 
Group By rd.room_no

Comment: i have used the group by clause bt m not getting the right answer,, Its counting only first top row.. what should be the crrct query, it is for checking availability of rooms and assigning first available room

Comment: replace "count(distinct rd.room_no)" by "(select count(distinct room_no) from room_details)". Check if this gives you what you want.

Comment: What do you mean its not working. Need more information than that! Error? Wrong result? Etc etc etc.